# Cohomology concept

Tags: general-topology, intuition, homology-cohomology

Can anyone describe the meaning and concept of cohomology in a visual non technical tongue? especially when it comes to topology. E.g. is there any way we can recognize the cohomology of a surface or shape just by looking at?

Comment: Welp, I was given the analogy of a man walking a dog on a retractable leash.  The dog can run around anywhere it wants and the man retracts the leash.  If the leash can get wound around insurmountable obstacles (such as holes in a torus) the potential unretractable loops can be viewed as a group.  As for seeing it.  Look and how many holes the space has.  Nonoriented  spaces involve having an obstacle surmountable after a finite number if iterations.

Comment: It's (possibly singular) oriented submanifolds modulo (possibly singular) oriented bordism. You can drop oriented if you work over $\Bbb Z/2$. This idea lets me calculate the homology (and thus cohomology ring, via Poincare duality) from a picture of a surface or 3-manifold.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [So what Cohomology is?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2296481/so-what-cohomology-is)